# Как при помощи JavaScript реализовать выделение элементов наподобие интерфейса Windows?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, pure-js

Как при помощи JavaScript реализовать возможность выделять несколько элементов подряд мышкой (как это происходит в Windows, чтобы еще была видна область выделения)? Ну и совместно с этим, чтобы работало выделение одним кликом, и при зажатой клавише <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> последовательное выделение элементов HTML (CheckBox, Input). *Кстати, все элементы с ***абсолютным*** позиционированием. **Без** использования всяких библиотек, либо с участием ExtJs не позже версии 3.1*.

Comment: Про "без библиотек", ИМХО, вы загнули. Как минимум, придется писать свою, чуть ли не вполовину jQuery.

Comment: Неужели так тяжело?
Просто jQuery как-то не очень работает поверх ExtJs.

Comment: Ну, если у вас уже есть ExtJs, это уже несколько упрощает задачу. Но, к сожалению, в [официальных примерах][1] используется версия 4.  
Во любом случае, я еще не видел подобных интерфейсов без использования сторонних библиотек.

[1]:http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/

Comment: Линг, ты уж загнул. =) Всего-то нужно выучить  
events:  
onmouseup, onmousedown, onmousemove;  
onkeypress; isctrlkey  
Чуток усвоить изменения CSS:
element.style.width  
И чуток вспомнить школьную геометрию.

Comment: @knes , все гениальное - просто. Я надеюсь, что есть готовые решения или кто-то когда-то это делал.

Comment: Если к 18 никто не напишет - пришлю решение: сейчас занят немного, а там писанины прилично, если использовать нативный JS.

Comment: @knes, буду благодарен, и очками поделюсь.  
-- Пишу не кроссбраузерно: только для Opera и Mozilla последних версий. Приложение внутри предприятия.  
И если в каждом элементе надо, чтобы у него был свой event или css-класс, то это тоже не проблема.

Comment: Ага, и выполнить это все кроссбраузерно. Плюс, как я понимаю, нужно аккуратное навешивание евентов не на элементы, а документ. Короче, парой строк тут явно не обойдешься.

Comment: И не обошлось. Самое сложное из кроссбраузерности - убрать выделение текста.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    .item{
        border: #956d1d 1px solid;
        background: #ffd171;
        width: 100px;
        height: 20px;
        margin: 7px;
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .item:hover{
        border: #183376 1px solid;
        background: #7f97d4;
        border-bottom-width: 2px;
        margin-bottom: 6px;
    }
    .itemSelected{
        border: #183376 1px solid;
        background: #6582c9;
        width: 100px;
        height: 20px;
        margin: 7px;
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .itemSelected:hover{
        border: #183376 1px solid;
        background: #7f97d4;
        border-bottom-width: 2px;
        margin-bottom: 6px;
    }
    #wlw{
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        overflow: scroll;
    }
    #selectFrame{
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        line-height: 0;
        border: 1px dotted #5c6a8e;
        background-color: #6582c9;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 100;
        visibility: hidden;
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=40)"; 
        filter: alpha(opacity=40);
        opacity: .4;
    }
</style>
<script>
msdown = false;
msx = 0;
msy = 0;
var selectedItems = new Array();
function disableSelection(target){
    if (typeof target.onselectstart!="undefined") //IE route
        target.onselectstart=function(){return false}
    else if (typeof target.style.MozUserSelect!="undefined") //Firefox route
        target.style.MozUserSelect="none"
    else //All other route (ie: Opera)
        target.onmousedown=function(){return false}
    target.style.cursor = "default"
}
function coords(e){
    var posx = 0;
    var posy = 0;
    if (e.pageX || e.pageY)     {
        posx = e.pageX;
        posy = e.pageY;
    }
    else if (e.clientX || e.clientY)    {
        posx = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft
            + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        posy = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop
            + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }

    return new Array(posx,posy);
}
document.onmousedown = function(e){
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    msdown = true;
    var mousexy = coords(e);
    msx = mousexy[0];
    msy = mousexy[1];
    return false;
}
document.onmousemove = function(e){
    var x1=0;
    var x2=0;
    var y1=0;
    var y2=0;
    var mousexy = coords(e);
    x1 = msx;
    y1 = msy;
    x2 = mousexy[0];
    y2 = mousexy[1];
    if (x1==x2){return;}
    if (y1==y2){return;}
    if (x1>x2){
        x1 = x1+x2;
        x2 = x1-x2;
        x1 = x1-x2;
    }
    if (y1>y2){
        y1 = y1+y2;
        y2 = y1-y2;
        y1 = y1-y2;
    }
    var sframe = document.getElementById('selectFrame');
    sframe.style.top = y1;
    sframe.style.left = x1;
    sframe.style.width = x2-x1;
    sframe.style.height = y2-y1;
    sframe.style.visibility = msdown?'visible':'hidden';
}
document.onmouseup = function(e){
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    msdown = false;
    var mousexy = coords(e);
    doSelection(msx,msy,mousexy[0],mousexy[1]);
    document.getElementById('selectFrame').style.visibility = msdown?'visible':'hidden';
}
function doSelection(x1,y1,x2,y2){
    if (x1==x2){return;}
    if (y1==y2){return;}
    if (x1>x2){
        x1 = x1+x2;
        x2 = x1-x2;
        x1 = x1-x2;
    }
    if (y1>y2){
        y1 = y1+y2;
        y2 = y1-y2;
        y1 = y1-y2;
    }
    selectedItems = new Array();
    var wlw = document.getElementById('wlw');
    for (var childItem in wlw.childNodes) {
        if (wlw.childNodes[childItem].nodeType == 1 && wlw.childNodes[childItem].id!='selectFrame'){
            var item = wlw.childNodes[childItem];
            if(item.offsetLeft>=x1 && item.offsetLeft<=x2 && item.offsetTop>=y1 && item.offsetTop<=y2){
                selectedItems.push(item.id);
                item.className = 'itemSelected';
            }else{
                item.className = 'item';
            }
        }
    }
}
function init(){
    var wlw = document.getElementById('wlw');
    for (var childItem in wlw.childNodes) {
        var item = wlw.childNodes[childItem];
        if(item.nodeType == 1 && item.id!='selectFrame'){
            item.onclick = function(e){
                if (!e) var e = window.event;
                if(e.ctrlKey){
                    selectedItems.push(this.id);
                    this.className = 'itemSelected';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
<div id="wlw">
<div id='selectFrame'></div>
    <div class="item" id="0">cfcd2</div>
        <div class="item" id="1">c4ca4</div>
        <div class="item" id="2">c81e7</div>
        <div class="item" id="3">eccbc</div>
        <div class="item" id="4">a87ff</div>
        <div class="item" id="5">e4da3</div>
        <div class="item" id="6">16790</div>
        <div class="item" id="7">8f14e</div>
        <div class="item" id="8">c9f0f</div>
        <div class="item" id="9">45c48</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Дальше справитесь?
Отсутствует: unselect(при повторном клике), ctrl+выделение, shift+click

первое реализуется дополнительной проверкой класса перед сменой в функции init, методе `onclick`
второе - проверкой нажатия кнопки ctrl при обнулении массива

```
selectedItems = new Array();
```

третье - самое сложное: надо запускать цикл по айдишникам при клике, причем запоминать предыдущий выделенный элемент.

Comment: А для Mozilla надо что-то свое писать?

Comment: Ну... у меня оно сработало в мозиллке. Единственное, там курсор некрасивый на тексте, но это исправляется стилями. У вас что не работает?

Comment: Ну, выделение сразу нескольких не работает.

Comment: Ага, точняк:  

    document.onmouseup = function(e){

Прошу прощения. =)
e пропустил. Просто 4-я мозиллка на это наплевала. А 3 и 5-я действительно не врубились че делать с !undefined

Comment: Спасибо громадное!

Answer (score 1):

Возможный [пример](http://javascript.ru/forum/events/17060-vydelenie-ehlementa-pri-navedenii.html) реализации

Comment: Ну, это часть большой задачи.