# Реализовать выделение картинок Windows как на рабочем столе и вывести в отдельный список названия картинок по нажатию кнопки

Tags: javascript, html

Возникла проблема с задачей, нужно сделать выделение как в Windows на рабочем столе при зажатии на левую кнопку мыши, только на языке JavaScript.

Также названия выделенных картинок нужно при нажатии на кнопку вывести в отдельный список.

Похожую задачу я нашёл [Как при помощи JavaScript реализовать выделение элементов наподобие интерфейса Windows?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/34533/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B8-javascript-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B0-w?newreg=1340371afea949f58954cccfd665c213), что изменить чтобы работало с картинками, а не с надписями.

Comment: А что вам мешает ее доделать?

Comment: Не понимаю как с картинками сделать тоже самое, кое как я вставил картинки,они даже выделялись,но в отдельный список названия картинок вывести, тут я без понятия